# How to select last three child elements with help of :nth-child

Tags: css

With this code I can select first three child elements:

`span:nth-child(-n+3)`

Is it possible to select last three child elements the same way?

Here's an example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqhtzkaw/

**UPDATE:**

Here's the answer: (thanks to Manoj Kumar)

```
/* First three items. */
span:nth-child(-n+3) {
}

/* Last three items. */
span:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infous/q61x0t3v/

Browsers that support it: http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-last-child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
span:nth-last-child(-n+3)
```

It selects the last 3 elements

Comment: But nope, it selects first three elements.. http://jsfiddle.net/nqhtzkaw/ I need last three elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/nqhtzkaw/1/

Comment: Oh, I didn't see `-last-` %) Now it works! Manoj Kumar, thanks!